# flex chart grid lines dotted

Tags: apache-flex, charts

Using the LineChart component of Flex: How do I make the horizontal grid lines (background within the chart) dotted? With the mx:Stroke within the mx:horizontalStroke, I can only set properties like weight, color and alpha. I'd like to make the line dotted...

This is what I have now:

```
<mx:LineChart id="linechartDays" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{dayData}" showDataTips="true">
    <mx:backgroundElements>
        <mx:GridLines horizontalChangeCount="1" direction="horizontal">
            <mx:horizontalStroke>
                <mx:Stroke weight="1" color="0xcccccc"/>
            </mx:horizontalStroke>
        </mx:GridLines>
    </mx:backgroundElements>
</mx:LineChart>
```

Answer (score -1):

use DottedLine.as class file for the following path http://www.warmforestflash.com/blog/2009/01/as3-dotted-line-class/

and use this function to main.mxml file

private function drawline(argStr:String):void
{
          var s:Shape= new DottedLine(1.5,Chart.height,0xff0000,1,5,4);
      uil=new UIComponent();
      uil.addChild(s);
      uil.height= Chart.height;
      canChart.addDataChild(uil,argStr,null,null,null,argStr,50);
}